# JS regex not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following code:

**searchSt** = "Test", **searchEd** = " in";

```
var html = body.clone()
    .children()
    .remove()
    .end()
    .text();

alert(searchSt + "|" + searchEd);
var patt = searchSt + "(.*)" + searchEd;
var result = html.match(patt);
alert(result[0]); //returns null
```

**This returns null although I am sure the words are there:
html:**

```
Hello World
Test Write SomeThing here is Words do it. hit in me
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using JQuery the code should be the following:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<body>
Hello World
Test Write SomeThing here is Words do it. hit in me 
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var searchSt = "Test", searchEd = " in";
    var html = $('body').clone().children().remove().end().text();

            alert(searchSt+"|"+searchEd);
            var patt = searchSt+"(.*)"+searchEd;
            var result = html.match(patt);
            alert(result[0]);//returns null

</script>
```

Make sure that script is placed below the body tag. If it's above than the body tag can't be found. And also I changed the way how to get body $('body').

There is no problem with regex

Comment: Nono, the parser will fix that and gently ignore the fact that your script is misplaced outside `body` (and even outside `html`). Use `$.ready()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Put a string regular expression inside the RegExp constructor (espacing the characters, if needed):

```
var re = new RegExp(searchSt + "(.*)" + searchEd); // => /Test(.*)in/
```

With inverted bars:

```
var re = new RegExp("\\d"); // => /\d/
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like its a regex problem. Probably something else.
Test here http://ideone.com/nNwz3

```
var html = "Hello World\
Test Write SomeThing here is Words do it. hit in me";

var searchSt = "Test", searchEd = " in";

var patt = searchSt+"(.*)"+searchEd;
var result = html.match(patt);

print ("'" + result[0] + "'");
print ("'" + result[1] + "'");
```

output

```
'Test Write SomeThing here is Words do it. hit in'
' Write SomeThing here is Words do it. hit'
```

Comment: I think it is because of the space before the in (searchEd).